# Highchart using tabs

Tags: javascript, node.js, tabs, highcharts

I have a html with a chart, but it has several information, so I need to divide into different tabs so I can show more specific information, I don't how to do it, I'm working with Node JS.

So in the JS where a create the chart a DIV tag (#Container) is being update in the HTML.

regards

Comment: SO you need to print chart in tab or dynamically append a div and then create a chart. For me its not clear.

Comment: The point is that I dont know how many tabs I'm gonna have, because it's up to the DB query, but for each tab will have a chart

Comment: You can create tab, use jquery append with defined id and then initialize chart.